# Watermarking Flash Videos (server-side)

Tags: flash, security, encoding, streaming, watermark

I have a bunch of flash videos that I need to watermark with user related information, to make illegal re-distribution of these files *harder*.

I'm wondering how can this be done server-side. If done client-side, it will be quite easy for the user to *intercept* the videos before they are watermarked.

Since the watermark should contain user-specific information I can't really watermark the videos before encoding them (unless I have an encoded video *per* user - not feasible).

I'm expecting this to affect the streaming performances a lot, though.

Any idea how this can be done (possibly in an efficient way)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**FFMPEG**](http://www.ffmpeg.org), a command line video tool to do this. It is cross-platform and easy enough to be used.

Watermarking example is shown in [this tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/video/add-watermark-video-ffmpeg).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I never realized, years ago anyhow, that watermarking a flash movie would be required for some of my productions... however, I had this little security method.
Build the main container of your movie with a script that checks for the url of your site's server as the window location.